# Git remove ignored __pycache__ directory after Python package rename

Tags: python, git

I have a Python package in my Git repository called `lib/requestAPI` that contains a `__pycache__` directory and three modules:

```
├── lib
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── requestAPI
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── checkwx.py
│   │   ├── github.py
│   │   └── weatherflow.py
```

I have added `__pycache__/` to my `.gitignore` file to ignore the contents of the `__pycache__` directory.

I recently renamed the Python package to `lib/request_api` and the names of the three modules. I pushed these changes to the remote server and then pulled the changes to a second machine. On this second machine, however, the `lib/requestAPI` folder remains as it contains the local `__pycache__` directory

```
├── lib
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── requestAPI
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   ├── request_api
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── checkwx_api.py
│   │   ├── github_api.py
│   │   └── weatherflow_api.py
```

Is there a Git command I can use to remove this extra `__pycache__` directory associated with the old package directory? I know I can use `git clean -d -X` to remove all ignored files and directories, but this also removes ignored configuration files which I don't want. Removing this folder manually is also not an option as the repository is distributed to many people

Comment: The short answer is no: if a file was never *in* Git, a `git checkout` or `git switch` won't *remove* it either. Untracked files (if they're really untracked: files listed in `.gitignore` could be tracked anyway, e.g., due to `git add -f` or other situations) didn't come out of Git and are not in Git and so Git won't remove them from the working tree, except via commands like `git clean`.

Comment: More generally, this sort of thing is why Git is not a deployment system. A deployment system is not a source code management system (though it shares some concepts): it knows which files should be removed by an upgrade, and which should not, even though none of those files are source files that a source code management system would know anything about.